# Can anyone tell me the name of the parent folder for kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.23. jar?

Tags: kotlin

I opened a Kotlin project that requires kotlin compiler embeddable-1.9.23.jar, but I used IntelliJ IDEA to download this dependency which is slow and always downloads again. So I downloaded the dependency myself from the website, but I don't know the name of its parent folder because it was generated by myself. Can anyone tell me?

I searched online and there is no answer to this question

Comment: It can't matter: the `.jar` files contain the folder structure for the package hierarchy themselves. You can look inside if you want, just make a copy of the file with `.zip` extension. What you do need is adding it to the classpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to add external jars (lib/\*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: @tevemadar It is located in the folder 'gradle\cache\modules-2\files 2.1\ org. jtbrains. kotlin\kotlin compiler embedded\1.9.23'. If you have this, can you help me take a look? This file is a Kotlin language compiler and cannot be used without it.